# GridView as child of FrameLayout with layout_weight

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

How to make the HxW of the `GridView` same as the HxW of the parent view (`FrameLayout`) ?

[image]

## xml :

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_menu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8">

            <GridView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/gridView"
                android:numColumns="2"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: the orange line means there is some space or padding around the gridview's bounds ?? is that what you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

set `Gravity` to  `android:gravity="fill_horizontal"` or `android:gravity="fill"`; and also use `android:stretchMode="columnWidth"`..

if it fails try to use `auto_fit`